# How do i set the Hinge Body.Connected Body to the previous Instantiated objects Rigid-body using last index of?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make an adjustable rope in unity and i basically made an array modifier.

I can get the last instantiated object using last index of but how do i get the hinge joint of the current object and add the rigid body of the previous object to the current objects connected body?

```
public class Rope : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject Segment1;
    int segmentName = 1;

    public int ropeLength; // length of rope
    GameObject[] segmentArray; // stores gameobjects in array

    Rigidbody[] segmentRb; // stores rigidbodys
    HingeJoint[] segmentHj; // stores Hingjoints

    Vector3 newSegmentLoc;

    void Start () {

        segmentArray = new GameObject[ropeLength];
        SpawnSegment();
    }

    void Update () {

    }

    void SpawnSegment(){ 

            void SpawnSegment(){ 

        for (int i = 1; i < ropeLength; i++) {

            segmentArray [i] = Instantiate (Segment1, newSegmentLoc, Quaternion.identity) as GameObject; // spawn in clones
            segmentArray [i].transform.parent = this.transform; // set parent of clones
            segmentArray [i].transform.name = segmentName.ToString (); // change the name of clones
            segmentName++;

            //int currentIndex = Array.IndexOf (segmentArray, segmentArray [i]);

            float yLoc = segmentArray [i].transform.position.y;
            newSegmentLoc = new Vector3 (0, yLoc - 1, 0);

            //int lastIndex = Array.LastIndexOf (segmentArray, segmentArray [i]);

            Rigidbody rb = segmentArray [i].gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
            HingeJoint hj = segmentArray [i - 1].gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().GetComponent<HingeJoint>();

            hj.connectedBody = rb;
        }

        Destroy (Segment1);

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your for-loop `i` already is the current index, you dont need to calculate it.
If you want the previous element, you simply say `segmentArray[i - 1]`, if you want the next `segmentArray[i + 1]`

but careful, they might not have been initialized. if youd currently try to geth segmentArray[i + 1], it would return null.

so you also might want to initialize the 0th element outside the loop. this allows you to start the loop with i = 1 and instead of connecting the current to the next, you connect the previous to the current.